# Can I revive Bhakti after I have completed his quest?

Tags: lightning-returns-final-fantasy-13

Very mild spoilers ahead for the Bhakti side quest.

Once you complete Bhakti's side quest, by bringing him his Bhakti oil, Bhakti tries to 'save' his friends. When he realises that humans need constant re-fuelling and have all died he powers down and is unresponsive.

Is there anyway to revive Bhakti after this point and can he give you any items, new quests etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no way to revive Bhakti - once he shuts down, that's the end of his story.

It's hard to find a solid reference for this without quoting an entire guide, but this is at least corroborated by [the Final Fantasy Wikia page on Bhakti](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Bhakti), which ends with the discussion that Hope and Lightning have about the potential for objects to have souls.